# Application break on setContentURL method call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok finally make my app to have setContentURL method. But now it's break my app, and I am so close to the end :(
This is where code breaks:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // please work!!!

    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"bla bla"];
    NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:title];

    [mp setContentURL:newURL];

}
```

This is method that is started when app is first time loaded, and it loads movie fine, problem in in call to setContentURL because thet is the point where my app crash:

```
- (void) readyPlayer
{
    mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
    {
        // Set movie player layout
        //[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES];

        // May help to reduce latency
        [mp prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }  
    else
    {
        // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil]; 

}
```

Comment: Start with debugger attached and watch the console and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate memory by performing [... alloc] but i don't see any autoreleases or releases... This might be the reason that the app crashes because ObjC doesn't have a garbage collector and you need to clean up yourself. If memory gets to high, your app will terminate.

Comment: I put release in dealloc method. Can you show me on some code what you exactly think?

Comment: Did you also release: NSString *title from your touchesBegan method? And i don't know how Xcode reacts to an URL with "bla bla" as it's content

Comment: I can't provide URL because it contains personal data. But it works 100%. Because if i put it in textfield on application start and press play button stream is loaded fine. Problem is just when I want to switch URL. And 'title' is released too.